# How to fill a temp table from stored procedure without knowing it's schema in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a question here regarding filling temp table from stored procedures in SQL Server. 
When we already have table schema of a table we can fill it from stored procedure as:

```
Create #tempTable (Id int, Value varchar(50))

Insert into #tempTable 
exec GetValues
```

Where `GetValues` returns the same schema as declared for `#tempTable`.

Here is another case when we fill a temp table from another table

```
Select colA,colB into #tempTableA from SomeTable
```

Here we don't need to know the schema of #tempTableA, it will be same as based on selected columns from table `SomeTable`.

My question is: how can we fill a `#temptable` without knowing it's schema, from a stored procedure? As we do when filling a temp table from some other table.

Comment: But you know the schema of `SomeTable`. Or you want to implement some sort of dynamic SQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure.

Comment: `INSERT @temp  Exec sp_helpfile;
select * from @temp;`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * INTO #tmpTable FROM OPENQUERY(YOURSERVERNAME, 'EXEC test.dbo.prc_test 1');
```

[Insert results of a stored procedure into a temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure)